# Registering Javascript with ScriptManager is working inconsistently

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET page. Currently there is no AJAX on the page. in the code behind for different button click events, I am registering the script below. The purpose of the script is to scroll the window to a particular anchor tag. The method is as follows:

```
public void RegisterAnchor(string anchorTag)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "navigate",
          "window.onload = function() {window.location.hash='#" + anchorTag + "';}", true);
}
```

I have two different anchor tags are that valid and defined in the same way.  However, one is working and one is not.
What can I check to identify the cause of this behavior?

Anchor tag in ascx:

```
<a name="EditDlg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to register client script using instance of the page. Other option is to generate unique script id every partial postback.

Option 1 (register client script with page instance):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Caller.GetType() , "navigate", "window.onload = function() {window.location.hash='#" + anchorTag + "';}", true);
```

Option 2 (generate unique script id every partial postback):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Caller, Caller.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid(), "window.onload = function() {window.location.hash='#" + anchorTag + "';}", true);
```

Comment: I modified the code in the question to be clearer.  I've tried using unique script ID's, but that didn't help.  This is not AJAX related, there's no AJAX on the page, so I'm using the Page.ClientScript, or at least trying to.  Thanks